# I want to be able to access archives to see how recently a post has been read: How can I do that?

Tags: archives

Is there a way to access archives to see which posts have been read recently?

Comment: I don't understand what is exactly what you want to do. Need more details, what kind of access? etc...

Comment: No, not unless you've been recording when your posts have been read. WordPress doesn't record this information on its own. If you want this sort of information your best bet would be to use some sort of analytics, like Google Analytics.